# Why AudioManager does not work for my Android app?

Tags: java, android, volume, android-audiomanager, tokbox

Any ideas why output audio volume should not be adjusted by this code? I am developing for Vuzix M400 and I am using Vonage Video API (Tokbox).

It works just fine on ordinary android smartphones so I searched Vuzix documentation and found that AudioManager is right way to adjust volume on this device.

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
    audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

I have tried:

- Set volume control stream on start of activity `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`
- Use Tokboxes CustomAudioDevice

  CustomAudioDevice customAudioDevice = new CustomAudioDevice(MainActivity.this);
  AudioDeviceManager.setAudioDevice(customAudioDevice);
- Use `adjustVolume` instead of `adjustStreamVolume`